# How to use phonegap FileTransfer parameters with .asmx web service

Tags: cordova, parameters, asmx, file-transfer

I am uploading an image to an asmx web service.  The file upload works fine, but I am wondering how to access the parameters that I set in the javascript for the filetransfer.

I want to pass the image number to the asmx SaveImage web method.  Then after the file has successfully been saved I want to return the image number to the Javascript.

//Javascript Calling Web Service 
   function uploadPhoto(imageURI, imageNumber) {

```
  var options = new FileUploadOptions(),
        params = {},
        ft = new FileTransfer(),
        percentLoaded = 0.0,
        progressBar = $(".image" + imageNumber + " > .meter > span");

    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";

    options.params = params;

    //get progress of fileTransfer for progress bar
    ft.onprogress = function (progressEvent) {
       if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
           percentLoaded = Math.round(100 * (progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total));
           progressBar.width(percentLoaded + "%");
       } else {
           //loadingStatus.increment();
       }
   };
   ft.upload(imageURI, "http://mysite.com/test/uploadPhotos.asmx/SaveImage", win, fail, options);
```

}

//.asmx web service

```
[WebMethod]
public string SaveImage()
{
    string rootPathRemote = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadedFilesPath"].TrimEnd('/', '\\') + "/";
    string rootPhysicalPathRemote = rootPathRemote + "\\";
    int fileCount = 0;

    fileCount = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[i];
        string fileName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[i].FileName;
        if (!fileName.EndsWith(".jpg"))
        {
            fileName += ".jpg";
        }
        string sourceFilePath = Path.Combine(rootPhysicalPathRemote, fileName);
        file.SaveAs(sourceFilePath);
    }
    return "test";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the parameters passed to the asmx web method you can use the Request.Params...

I added the following lines to my code

javascript //add a parameter with a key of imageNum

```
params.imageNum = imageNumber;
```

added to .asmx [Web Method]

```
string allParams = "";
NameValueCollection parameters = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params;
string[] imageNum = parameters.GetValues("imageNum");
for (int j = 0; j < imageNum.Length; j++)
{
    allParams += imageNum[j].ToString();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493196/phonegap-file-transfer-plugin-parameters-to-asp-net-service?noredirect=1#comment50961804_31493196