# phonegap 2.5.0 in IOS filetransfer upload image, return 405 and code 3

Tags: ios, cordova, file-transfer

i have a problem with FileTransfer.upload image in IOS, i use the example you gave:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

when i call to FileTransfer.upload from ios i get code 3 and HTTP status 405. i try to use from server side with ashx(handler) file.

**all this working fine from android, Code is exactly the same in both.**

my code:

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var fileImageTransfer = new FileTransfer();

    fileImageTransfer.upload(imageURI, domain + "/handlers/imageupload.ashx?greetingID=5", win, fail, options);
}
```

For two days without success
please help me.

10X .

Comment: Same question and answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458099/how-to-use-phonegap-filetransfer-parameters-with-asmx-web-service

Comment: no, this not my problem...

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the server logs to see what is causing the 405 "Method not allowed" error. See how the file is being requested.

Comment: why isn't it consistent amongst android and ios?