# PhoneGap file transfer plugin parameters to ASP.NET service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cordova, file-upload, phonegap-plugins

I want to pass parameters from the PhoneGap file transfer plugin to an ASP.NET MVC web service.

So I prepared `Params` in JavaScript :

```
 var Params = {};
    Params.Order = $("#Order").val();
alert($("#Order").val());//It works it is not null
    Params.latitude = $("#latitude").val();
    Params.longitude = $("#longitude").val();
    options.Params = Params;
    ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(sPicData, encodeURI("../Mobile/UploadPhoto"), win, fail, options);
```

Now I want to acces the `Params` from my ASP.NET MVC web service, but this code gives an error (`Null exception`).

```
   [HttpPost] 
    public JsonResult  UploadPhoto()
    {
         // File upload code here and it works well.
         // File upload work but there is problem with Params
         System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection parameters = Request.Params;
         string[] imageNum = parameters.GetValues("Order");
// string order=imageNum[0]
         string[] latitude = parameters.GetValues("latitude");
         string[] longitude = parameters.GetValues("longitude");
//other codes
    }
```

Comment: GetValues will return null if the parameter is not present, have you set a breakpoint and checked if the parameters are present in the parameters collection

Comment: how can i set breakpoint?the camera file transfer plugin use in mobile device...before I send  values (such as order,latitude,longtitude ) I alert them that values not null.But when send service in service I can not access them because it is give null exception error

Comment: In the .net service st a breakpoint before the params are accessed, to check if any of the params have been sent

Comment: HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files; this is set with files but  System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection parameters = Request.Params; this is null

Comment: try with var params = {}; (lowercase)

Answer (score 0):

```
function photoUpload() {

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = sPicData.substr(sPicData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    var params = new Object();

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position) {
        params.fileKey = "file";
        params.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        params.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        params.altitude = position.coords.altitude;
        params.accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
        params.altitudeAccuracy = position.coords.altitudeAccuracy;
        params.heading = position.coords.heading;
        params.speed = position.coords.speed;
        params.timestamp = position.timestamp;

        //alert(params.longitude + ',' + params.latitude);

        options.params = params;

        ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(sPicData, "http://YOURSERVER/upload.aspx", win, fail, options); 
        });
```

}

Try this, it works for me.
Just grab the geo data in the different params as ordinary posted form fields.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem here.  [How to use phonegap FileTransfer parameters with .asmx web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458099/how-to-use-phonegap-filetransfer-parameters-with-asmx-web-service)

Try changing

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection parameters = 
    Request.Params;
```

to

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection parameters = 
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Params;
```