# Retrieve HTTP headers in Cordova File Transfer ASP Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, cordova

I'm trying to retrieve an custom header from cordova file transfer.
I'm sending an photo image with the header along (HTTP Post).

Cordova side:

```
...
var server = 'http://192.168.2.48/webservice.asmx/SaveImage';
var headers={'id':'123'};
var ftOptions = new FileUploadOptions();
ftOptions.fileKey = 'file';
ftOptions.fileName = imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
ftOptions.mimeType = 'image/jpeg';
ftOptions.httpMethod = 'POST';
ftOptions.headers = headers;
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
fileTransfer.upload(imageData, encodeURI(server), win, fail, ftOptions);
```

ASP side(to retrieve 'file'):

```
HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];
```

I'm able to retreive my image data but **unable to get the headers** ('id'), any suggestions and ideas would be appreciated.

Plugin GitHub Link: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jcesarmobile guidance, googled and found the solution from [How to use phonegap FileTransfer parameters with .asmx web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458099/how-to-use-phonegap-filetransfer-parameters-with-asmx-web-service).

Using params:

```
var params = {};
params.id = "123";
ftOptions.params = params;
```

ASP Side:

```
string allParams = "";
NameValueCollection parameters = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params;
string[] imageNum = parameters.GetValues("id");
for (int j = 0; j < imageNum.Length; j++)
{
    allParams += imageNum[j].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Headers aren't what you need, you need params

```
var params = {};
params.id = "123";

ftOptions.params = params;
```

Then, on the server, use this code to get the POST data

```
Request.Form["id"];
```